# React native text not wrapping on Native Base Title

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I can't seem to get my title text to wrap:

[image]

[I'm using native-base](http://nativebase.io/)

```
let SearchPage = (props) => {
  const menu = (
    <Container>
      <Header style={styles.header}>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent onPress={props.togglePageMenu}>
            <Icon name='menu' />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2}>Search Products</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
        </Right>
      </Header>...
```

styles...:

```
      title: {
        flexWrap:'wrap',
        flex: 1,
        color: '#9E9E9E',
        fontWeight: '200',
        fontSize: 19
      },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7'
  },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use alignItems: 'flex-start' instead of flexWrap:'wrap'

Answer (score 1):

I had to stop using `<Title>` from Native Base and instead use `<Text>` from Native Base. I guess `Title` has some behind the scenes styles that prevent it from wrapping.

Comment: did you try wrap with alignitems?